# Using facebook sdk to show ALL mutual friends, not just those who have the app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the facebook javascript sdk and I want to show ALL mutual friends between those users, not just those who have the app.

Using the api documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user.context/mutual_friends), I can only see a list of mutual facebook friends who have the app.

How can I get complete list of mutual friends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional notes on that page explain it fairly well why you cannot get all.

- A valid user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the mutual friends of other friends using the app.
- The user in the request and the session user must both have granted user_friends permission to the app.
- Additionally, the response will only include any mutual friends who have granted user_friends to the app.

That is, the only way to get a complete list of mutual friends is if all your friends signed up to your app and granted user_friends permissions

Comment: True, however services like Tinder and Lulu do show mutual friends that do not have the app. How is that possible?

Comment: @johncorser Tinder is most likely using v1 of the API which is no longer available for new apps read the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Oh! I have an app that is still on the v1 api. Will it ever stop working?

Comment: @johncorser yes this is all explained in the changelog linked, April 30, 2015. If your v1 app was inactive for the past few months it would have been automatically been pushed to v2 API. Try not to think of ways to implement a feature soon to be removed. Recommended upgrade period is approaching https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/93xgoBi8C-x.png

Comment: I've searched absolutely everywhere for a work around, but to no end. Throwing in the towel and accepting this answer as final.

Thanks @phwd

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, there is an endpoint to fetch all mutual friends:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user-context/all_mutual_friends

> Returns a list of all the Facebook friends that the session user and the request user have in common. This includes friends who use the app as well as non-app-using mutual friends.

It also says you must request this endpoint from your server, not an app client.

Comment: Hi there, i am using a java server app for my api, how can i implement this with my server to return the mutual friends between the request user and target user? Do i need to store both of the user's facebook access tokens on my server?

Comment: @LucasSenechal just take a look at that documentation page. Your request to facebook will need to include the authenticated user's token from facebook, as well as the facebook user ID of the other party. You do not need both access tokens. Just the token for your authenticated user.

Comment: Ahh Thank you! I am trying to implement this right now. my only concern is i tried hitting the rest api with the proper format form the facebook documentation and the only user i got back was the user i was targetting? what is the proper format for me to go test on the facebook graph explorer before i try implementing it on my server? also my server is running a java web app so i downloaded restfb and implemented it into my java application but im not sure if that is the right way to go about doing that?

Comment: I do think that both users must be authenticated with your application in order to get their mutual friends. That might be your problem.

Comment: We both are authenticated and have given the proper permissions

Answer (score 1):

```
    function aa_mutl_frnd(x, row)
{ 
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<?php echo get_option('_fb_apps_id');?>', //Facebook apps id using theme option
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });  
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        console.log(':acc_tk:'+accessToken);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var data={
            'action': 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt',
            'ddt'   :  accessToken
        }

        $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (response) {
            console.log(':acc_tk2:'+response);


        FB.api(
                "/"+x+"",
                {
                    "fields": "context.fields(all_mutual_friends)",
                    //"access_token": '',
                    "appsecret_proof": response,
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);     
                }
        );

        });
////////////////////////////////////
        }
  });

}
/// ajax part /////
add_action('wp_ajax_wq_accss_tkn_gnrt', 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wq_accss_tkn_gnrt', 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt');    
    function wq_accss_tkn_gnrt() {
        echo hash_hmac('sha256',$_POST['ddt'],'app_secret');;
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    get facebook friends

    $access_token = "facebook token";
    $app_secret = "facebook secret";
    $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, 
    $app_secret);


    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=context.fields(/me?fields=id,name,friends.limit(99)" . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&appsecret_proof=" . $appsecret_proof;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response_mutual = json_decode($output, true);
    curl_close($ch);
```